# Using apply function on a matrix in R

Tags: r

I have a matrix in R which is in the following format:

```
A B C D E
1 0 0 1 0
0 0 1 0 1
1 1 1 0 1
.
.
.
```

I need to compare, for each column the value in the row, with the corresponding value in the column D & E. For example:

```
if(mat[1,1] == 1 && mat[1,4]==1)
   vec[1]+=1
else if(mat[1,1] == 1 && mat[1,5]==1)
   vec[1]-=1
```

Basically, `vec` will be positive if number of 1s in column 4 is greater than number of 1s in column 5.

For this I pass use a apply function which calls the elements row wise, and then I run a loop from 1 to the number of columns, and perform the above conditions as shown below:

```
outputv = vector(,ncol(mat))

A <- function(vec){

    for(i in 1:length(vec)-2)
      {
         if(vec[i]==1 &&vec[length(vec)-1]==1)
             outputv[i] = outputv[i] + 1
         else if(vec[i] == 1&& vec[length(vec)-2]==1)
             outputv[i] = outputv[i] - 1
      }

}
apply(mat,1,A)
```

I do realize the loop isnt an efficient method, but even with this approach, the values in outputv are all 0.

The expected outputv for the given input matrix would be

```
0 1 2
```

For the first column, 1 appears in the 1st and 3rd row. In the first row 4th column, there is 1, subtract 1. 3rd 5th Column has 1, so add 1
Total = -1 + 1 = 0

Comment: @akrun I added the expected output

Comment: @akrun Only when there is a 1, should we check the value in the last and second last column

Comment: In the first n-2 columns, go row wise..if there exists a 1, check for that row what is the value of the last and second last column

Comment: For example, in the first row, A has 1, but B, C are 0. and E is also 0, So, I guess we should check 'D'.  In the second row, C is 1 and E is 1.  Sorry, didn't get the condition

Comment: Do not compare all columns at once. Treat each column separately. So for 1st column check with last and second last. 2nd column with last and second last and so on. Last 2 columns its not required to compare with each other. Same procedure has to be applied for all rows.

Comment: I tried `rowSums((m1[,1:3]==1 & m1[,4]==1 ) +(m1[,1:3]==1 & m1[,5]==1))
#[1] 1 1 2`, but it is not giving the expected output you asked.  May be your condition is different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logical operation & is equivalent to binary multiplication. So you can simplify your condition to columnwise multiplication and then calculating sums.

```
> mat <- as.matrix(read.table(
+ text = "
+ A B C D E
+ 1 0 0 1 0
+ 0 0 1 0 1
+ 1 1 1 0 1", header = TRUE ) )
> 
> outputv <- rep(0, ncol(mat)-2 )     # initialize vector with zeros
> 
> for (n in 1:(ncol(mat)-2) )         # calculate outputv in loop
+   outputv[n] <- sum( mat[,n]*(-mat[,ncol(mat)-1] +mat[,ncol(mat)]) )   
> outputv
[1] 0 1 2
> vec <- sum(outputv)
> vec
[1] 3
```

But the best (and fast) solution may be this approach based on matrix multiplication:

```
- (mat[,ncol(mat)-1] %*% mat[,1:(ncol(mat)-2)] ) +
  mat[,ncol(mat)] %*% mat[,1:(ncol(mat)-2)]
```

It gives desired output:

```
     A B C
[1,] 0 1 2
```

Comment: Wont this take sum of all the 1s in the last and second last column ?

Comment: This will count for `i`-th column sum of two sumproducts `i`-th column by minus D and by plus E. For column A for example, `mat[1,1] * ( -mat[1,4]) + mat[1,1] * mat[1,5] + mat[2,1] * ( -mat[2,4]) + mat[2,1] * mat[2,5] + mat[3,1] * ( -mat[3,4]) + mat[3,1] * mat[3,5]`. That's equivalent to your first code example, with the difference in signs of D and E columns, cause in further explanations you mention we should substract D and add E. Btw, your function gives zeros because it doesn't affect vector `outputv` really. To do it you need global assignment like this: `outputv[i] <<- outputv[i] + 1`

Comment: I Understood. Thanks! Is there a way to avoid the loop? My data set is pretty huge and the loop is slowing it down!

Comment: In my answer there is loop over columns. If you don't have thousands of columns it should work fast, because columns are treated as vectors of length equal to the number of rows in matrix, and this way is efficient. There is way to use `apply` instead of `for` but that will not give great improvement in speed.

Comment: I Have about 2500 columns!

Comment: Edited my answer, hope this will be OK for you :)